# Jquery loading effect

Tags: jquery, load

in my index page, i've code like this :

```
function cek(){
        $container = $("#containermsg").notify();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.2.45:49/KP/UploadManager/filemover',
            cache: false,
            success: function(datas){
                $("#filemovernotif").html(datas);
            }
        });
        var waktucek = setTimeout("cek()",900000); //satuan ms
    }
```

i want to run the url every 90000 ms, but it not run well, because this code will run every time page loaded/refreshing.

i also want to ask about page loading effect for this code. The objective of url:'http://192.168.2.45:49/KP/UploadManager/filemover' is to uploading the content of many large file into database, so it run about 1 minutes or more. How can i show loading progress on the page while filemover doing uploading progress. i'm sorry for my bad english. Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
As far as I know timer always run until it is cleared out, so declaring it once is enough.

Restructure your code and take `waktucek` variable outside of the function. And about loading, a quick idea is: after ajax function call show a loading image anywhere and inside success(when upload is complete) just remove the image:

```
function cek(){
        $container = $("#containermsg").notify();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.2.45:49/KP/UploadManager/filemover',
            cache: false,
            success: function(datas){
        // Remove the src
        $("#statusDivImg").src(null);

        $("#filemovernotif").html(datas);
            }
        });

       // Show loading image
       $("#statusDivImg").src("/path/to/loading/image");
    }

// Timer set
var waktucek = setTimeout("cek()",900000); //satuan ms
```

Comment: i'm so sorry for editing your comment.newbie, i don't know if any changing happen for it. thank's for your replying, i'll try it and i'll ask if i got something wrong. thank you.

Comment: i'm sorry. the code is not work for me. this line is the cause if it : $("#statusDivImg").src("../images/ajax-loader.gif");
after i remove this line, the page is page is loaded like before. No loading effect run.,how can i solve this. Thank's in advance..

Comment: @Siregar: Try this- `$("#statusDivImg").attr("src","../images/ajax-loader.gif")`;

Comment: still not work.,i want to show loading picture with block page (block.ui) when execute the url. Confuse to implementing this..

Comment: actually my code is like this
$(function() {
 cek();
 cek_notif();
});
function cek_n(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://192.1',
  cache: false,
  success: function(datas){
   $("#no
 var waktucek = setTimeout("cek_n()",6000);
}
function cek(){
 $container = $("#msg").notify();   
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://192.1',
  cache: false,
  success: function(datas){
   $("#statusDivImg").src(null);
   $("#filemovernotif").html(datas);
  }
 });
 var waktucek = setTimeout("cek()",60000);
 $("#statusDivImg").attr("src","../images/ajax-loader.gif");
}

Comment: i want to make like this http://itprism.com/blog/ajax-loading-overlay
but the trigger is while the url executed, not link clicked. and i use jquery-1.4.2.js plugin.,

still not work until now.,

Comment: @Siregar: You can use `.trigger()` to call any custom function. On the other hand if you bind the `onclick` property of the link it should work also. Useful reference: http://api.jquery.com/trigger and http://api.jquery.com/click/